# How to calculate percentage of features without zero in all columns in R?

Tags: r, dataframe

I have a dataframe with first column as `features` and other columns with values in the set {0,1,2,-1,-2}.

Here is the dataframe structure.

```
df <- structure(list(Features = structure(c(1L, 11L, 12L, 13L, 14L, 
15L, 16L, 17L, 18L, 2L, 3L, 4L, 5L, 6L, 7L, 8L, 9L, 10L), .Label = c("Var1", 
"Var10", "Var11", "Var12", "Var13", "Var14", "Var15", "Var16", 
"Var17", "Var18", "Var2", "Var3", "Var4", "Var5", "Var6", "Var7", 
"Var8", "Var9"), class = "factor"), Column1 = c(0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 
0L, 0L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 0L, 0L, -1L, -1L, -1L, 0L, 0L), Column2 = c(0L, 
0L, 0L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, -2L, -2L, -2L, -2L, -2L, 
0L, 0L), Column3 = c(0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 
0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L), Column4 = c(0L, 0L, 0L, 2L, 
2L, 2L, 2L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, -2L, -2L, -2L, -2L, 0L, 0L), 
    Column5 = c(0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 
    1L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L), Column6 = c(0L, 0L, 0L, 2L, 2L, 
    2L, 0L, 0L, -1L, -1L, -1L, -1L, -1L, -1L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L), 
    Column7 = c(-1L, -1L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, -1L, -1L, -1L, 
    -1L, -1L, -1L, -1L, -1L, -1L, -1L), Column8 = c(1L, 1L, 1L, 
    1L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 1L, 1L, 1L
    )), class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, -18L))
```

For each column I wanted to calculate the percentage of features without 0 in the columns.

Any help is appreciated. Many thanks.

Comment: Can u show the expected output for the example

Comment: Do you want to know which rows do not have a zero in all columns?

Comment: @Cettt For each column I want to know percent of features which are not having 0's in the columns.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We can use `colSums` and divide by number of rows in the dataframe

```
colSums(df[-1] != 0)/nrow(df)

#Column1 Column2 Column3 Column4 Column5 Column6 Column7 Column8 
#  0.444   0.500   0.333   0.444   0.500   0.500   1.000   0.778
```

---

Or using `dplyr`

```
library(dplyr)
df %>%  summarise_at(-1, ~sum(.!= 0)/n())
```

Comment: Thanks a lot. What is -1 here?

Comment: @beginner It is to ignore the 1st column here since you do not want to calculate it for `Features` column.

Answer (score 2):

Maybe something like the following will do what you want.
`df[-1] != 0` returns a logical matrix, its `colSums` are the number of non-zero entries in each column. Divide by the number of rows and multiply by 100 to get the percentage you want.

```
100*colSums(df[-1] != 0)/nrow(df)
# Column1   Column2   Column3   Column4   Column5 
# 44.44444  50.00000  33.33333  44.44444  50.00000 
#  Column6   Column7   Column8 
# 50.00000 100.00000  77.77778
```

Answer (score 2):

We can just use `colMeans` on a logical `matrix`

```
colMeans(df[-1] != 0)
#    Column1   Column2   Column3   Column4   Column5   Column6   Column7   Column8 
# 0.4444444 0.5000000 0.3333333 0.4444444 0.5000000 0.5000000 1.0000000 0.7777778
```

---

Or using `tidyverse`

```
library(tidyverse)
map_dbl(df[-1], ~ mean(.x != 0))
```